# Setpoint weighting algorithm for the PI controller

Tags: control, transfer-function, pid-controller, closed-loop

Some time ago I found an interesting modification of the standard PI controller algorithm.
The modification is called the setpoing weighting in the literature and regards the proportional component of the PI controller. In the continuous time domain the the modified proportional component is calculated in following manner

$$u_P(t) = Kp\cdot\beta\cdot r(t) - Kp\cdot y(t),$$

where \$u_P(t)\$ is the contribution to the action value comming from the proportional component, \$K_p\$ is the proportional gain, \$\beta\$ is the setpoint weighting factor \$(0 <= \beta <= 1)\$ and \$y(t)\$ is the controlled value.

As far as I understood the algorithm in correct manner it enables to have two proportional
gains:

- Proportional gain for the reference tracking which equals to \$K_p\cdot\beta\$
- Proportional gain for the disturbance rejection which equals \$K_p\$

Let's say I have following closed-loop system

[image]

for which following equation holds

$$Y(s) = R(s)\cdot\frac{G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)}{1 + G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)} + D(s)\cdot\frac{G_P(s)}{1 + G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)}$$

Based on that I can write two transfer functions

- transfer function for the reference input
  $$G_R(s) = \frac{G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)}{1 + G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)}$$
- transfer function for the disturbance input
  $$G_D(s) = \frac{G_P(s)}{1 + G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)}$$

I have been attempting to find a relationship between the above mentioned transfer functions
and the setpoint weighting algorithm. I have attempted to summarize the idea which I have
below.

From the high point of view it could be said that our goal is to have

- \$G_R(s) \rightarrow 1\$, which enables to have \$Y(s) = R(s)\$
- \$G_D(s) \rightarrow 0\$, which enables to have the controlled value immune to the disturbance

The first requirement will be fullfilled in case \$|G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)| >> 1\$ because in such case I can neglect the "1" in the denominator of the \$G_R(s)\$. Necesarry condition for fullfillment of the second requirement is \$|G_C(s)\cdot G_P(s)| >> 1\$ because in such case I can again neglect the "1" in the denominator of the \$G_D(s)\$. As far as I do that I can write \$G_D(s) \approx \frac{1}{G_C(s)}\$. The last relation in my opinion justify the fact that for the disturbance rejection I need higher gain of the controller which is basically addressed by the setpoint weighting algorithm. That is based on the fact that in case following holds \$|G_C(s)|\rightarrow\infty\$ then \$G_D(s)\rightarrow 0\$.

My question is whether my understanding of the relationship between the setpoint weighting algorithm and the transfer functions \$G_R(s)\$ and \$G_C(s)\$ is correct. In other words I am not sure whether the relation \$G_D(s) \approx \frac{1}{G_C(s)}\$ realy justifies the fact that I need to have higher gain for the disturbance rejection than for the reference tracking.

**EDIT**:

In case the so called setpoint weighting algorithm is applied the proportional part of the controller looks like this

[image]

Comment: **1** Please mark where \$u_P (t)\$ would be on the  diagram. In your diagram you *already mix \$r(t)\$ and \$y(t)\$ in the ratio \$1:1\$ and not \$\beta : 1\$*. **2** If your *error-signal* has unequal weights for \$r(t)\$ and \$y(t)\$, and assuming that a control system tries to bring the *error-signal* to zero (and system is purely linear), then clearly \$G_R(s) \rightarrow \beta\$. **3** This looks like *feed-forward* control (augmentation) by another name. Excuse me if I misunderstood your question. **4** Are all the systems above LTI ?

Comment: With the added diagram, I would say that the expression for \$G_R(s)\$ is not correct.